# How to deploy React app to Google Cloud Vm Instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, frontend, google-cloud-compute-engine

I have a basic hello world react app and Google cloud server in compute machine(Vm Instance).How can I deploy my react app to this server?

Comment: This is completely unanswerable, state the specific problem you have and what you already tried.

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to deploy my react app to google cloud compute engine server.I tried many ways in youtube but they did in app engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy react apps to google cloud platform with App Engine only. Follow the below steps:

1. Creating the react app
2. Creating the app.yaml file
3. Creating a new Project in Google console
4. Creating App Engine
5. Deploying Google App Engine
6. Deploying using Google Cloud SDK
7. Deploying using Google Cloud Shell
8. Configuring a Custom Domain in Google App Engine.

Refer to this [document](https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-deploy-google-cloud-app-engine) for more detailed steps.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I did what you say with google cloud shell.Then they give me link.But when I make changes, it does not appear in the link.What can I do?